# Runtime Error 1004 Method "Range" of object "_Worksheet" failed

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to combine numerous sheets into one new sheet. I would really appreciate any comments.

The issue is with the line:

```
wsSrc.Range("A1", wsSrc.Range("D", lastRow)).Copy Destination:=rngDest
```

Which causes the error when I try to run it. I have previously been using the code to combine all the sheets into the sheet Summary which is where the button for the macro is created which worked fine.

```
Sub mcrCombine()

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "Combined" 'Create new sheet

'Definitions
Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim rngDest As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim destRow As Long
Set wsDest = Worksheets("Combined") 'Destination sheet in same Workbook
Set rngDest = wsDest.Range("B1") 'Destination cell in Combined
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'suppress prompt worksheet delete

'loop through all sheets
For Each wsSrc In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If wsSrc.Name <> "Summary" And wsSrc.Name <> "Combined" Then 'all sheets except summary
        lastRow = wsSrc.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row 'define     last row
        wsSrc.Range("A1", wsSrc.Range("D", lastRow)).Copy Destination:=rngDest 'copy and paste data in range
        Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(lastRow - 1) 'update destination range
        wsSrc.Delete 'delete source file
    End If
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'prompts back on
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've tried that and am still receiving the same error. I'll amend the code in my question.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I am not sure that this will get your code to achieve all what it is supposed to do, but since you corrected to issue pointed out by @Jeeped and  specified your issue within this line:

> `wsSrc.Range("A1", wsSrc.Range("D", lastRow)).Copy Destination:=rngDest`

The error in this line is because of the comma instead of the ampersand. You should change it into:

```
wsSrc.Range("A1", "D" & lastRow).Copy Destination:=rngDest
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> I have previously been using the code to combine all the sheets into the sheet Summary which is where the button for the macro is created which worked fine.

That's the clue as to what is occurring. As you cycle through each of the worksheets in the workbook you take care not to process the **Summary** worksheet; probably because a) it already holds aggregated information from the other worksheets and b) you do not want it deleted with the other worksheets that are processed.

If you have changed the central location to a **Combined** worksheet you are going to have to include that in the worksheet(s) to skip over. Failure to skip over the **Combined** worksheet will a) copy its content on top of itself and b) delete the **Combined** worksheet.

```
If wsSrc.Name <> "Summary" And wsSrc.Name <> "Combined" Then
```

If you delete the **Combined** worksheet, then there is Nothing in the way of a destination.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have tried that and it is still presenting the same error with the same line. Do you have any other ideas to what it might be?

Comment: Besides, `wsSrc.Range("A1", wsSrc.Range("D", lastRow)).Copy...` should be `wsSrc.Range("A1", "D" & lastRow).Copy ...` (ampersand, not comma).

Comment: @A.S.H - I'd post that as the answer. I got caught up with *"I have previously been using ..." and didn't realize it should have been an `&` or `wsSrc.Cells(lastRow, "D"))`.

Comment: Yep, that's a good observation. I only emphasize that there many other things that the OP has to fix in the code.